# Blood Bowl: Would a Dwarf team of mostly blockers be feasible?

Tags: blood-bowl

I'm planning on building a team of blockers and one runner in Blood Bowl. This is my team:

- 10 blockers (Block, Tackle, Thick Skull) @70k each = 700k
- 1 runner (Sure Hands, Thick Skull) @80k = 80k
- 5 re-rolls @40k each = 200k

My reasoning is:

1. Dwarf blockers start with lots of great skills and form a cage well
2. I only need 1 runner, as passing is hard for dwarves
3. The troll slayers and deathroller are too unreliable due to frenzy/being sent off at the end of a drive respectively
4. Blitzers don't have tackle

My question is, **is this a competitive build?**

PS. I'm new to Blood Bowl. I've played half a dozen games using [Living Rulebook 5](http://www.bloodbowlonline.com/LivingRulebook5.pdf)

Comment: This seems very subjective

Comment: @AndrewVandever - There is nothing wrong with subjective questions on this site as long as the answers can be backed up with "facts, references, or specific expertise"

Comment: @PatLudwig To make sure I understand, "Here is a list of tourneys won by such a build" would be an acceptable "yes" answer, while "i searched tournament winners and runners-up and found no such examples" would be an acceptable negative answer?

Comment: @AndrewVandever - I'd rather see answers from experienced Blood Bowl players giving their thoughts on the proposed team including how they've seen similar teams fare in the past.

Comment: If you get behind, by one touchdown, you will lose.  Otherwise, yes, feasible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not a competitive build.

Longbeards are very slow. Only treemen and mummies are slower in the modern game. Their agility is also poor, requiring a 4+ to pick up, catch or dodge, even without any negative modifiers.

Frenzy is not a weakness on the Trollslayers - it's a strength. Dwarf cages can be relatively easy to stall as it's very difficult for them to break the pattern of pillars that are often used to slow a cage down, particularly near a sideline. With frenzy you threaten teams that pillar near a sideline, as to do so risks their players to being pushed into the crowd.

Taking only one player with enough agility to handle the ball reliably is also a risk. A thrown rock or a fortunate armour roll against av8 and you will be left without the ability to score, or move more than 4 spaces without GFIs. For this reason it's more typical to run with both blitzers and two runners (though not universal).

You likely won't need five rerolls as you get more used to risk management. And you should seek out a newer version of the rules, as the one you're using is out of date - try googling LRB6, CRP (Competition Rules Pack) or Icepelt.